# Need Linq Help Selecting List of Tags Using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a JSON file that contains a list of icons by Key that each have a list of Tags. It looks like this:

```
{
  "IconTags": [
    {
      "Key": "Com_Active",
      "Tags": [
        "Green",
        "Circle",
        "Active"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Com_Add",
      "Tags": [
        "Green",
        "Plus",
        "Add"
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

At runtime, using JSON.NET, I want to parse the JSON for a specific icon Key and return a List of the Tags.

Here is what I currently have:

```
JObject iconTags = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"IconTags.json"));

var tags = from i in iconTags["IconTags"] 
    where i["Key"].Value<string>() == "Com_Add" 
    select i["Tags"].Values<string>();
```

This works, but it returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>>`.

I want my Linq query to just return `IEnumerable<String>`.

Can any of you wonderful experts help me with my Linq query?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SelectMany instead, that will flatten all of the enumerables.

```
iconTags["IconTags"].Where(i => i["Key"].Value<string>() == "Com_Add" )
 .SelectMany(i => i["Tags"].Values<string>());
```

You can get more info at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) article

Comment: The SelectMany function is missing the Anders arrow. Should be: `.SelectMany(i => i["Tags"].Values<string>());`

Comment: @Keith thanks, I missed that I was writing it quickly, I made those changes

Comment: I really like using this syntax. Is there a way I can accept two answers as correct?

Comment: @Keith, the answer you choose above will only get the first enumerable, instead of flattening them you probably will be missing results.  e.g  if you have an enumerable of enumerables it will just grab that first enumerable and ignore the rest

Comment: @Keith I also prefer this syntax, at first it was a bit confusing, but it looks more like code than sql, and its easy to read most of the time

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like this instead:

```
var tags = (from i in iconTags["IconTags"] 
where i["Key"].Value<string>() == "Com_Add" 
select i["Tags"].Values<string>()).First();
```

It will return the first element of the enumerable you're getting